# Getting latitude and longitude raster from DEM using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, latitude-longitude

Could anyone provide with a way to calculate latitude and longitude from DEM, for each raster cell?

In previous posts about this, I have seen that some suggest calculating lat and long in certain sample point locations. This doesn't work for me, as I need complete rasters.

Also, I use ArcGIS 10.2 version so $$XMAP, $$YMAP does not work for me.

Is there any other way inside ArcGIS to get lat and long?

Comment: marika, you can convert your raster to points and than use the x and y of each point representing each raster cell.

Comment: Another option is to export your raster as asc and use the coordinates reference and the pixel size to get all your cells.

Comment: The coordinate boundary (ulx/uly/lrx/lry) is a property of any raster.  Coordinate location **not** generally seen as a property of individual cells, *per se*, since such an extraction would increase the size manifold.  What are you going to do with this information, and in what programming language?

Comment: I want to use latitude and longitude as explanatory variables in a multiple regression model. I will use R.

Comment: read the dem with raster() and use functions coordinates, xFromCol, yFromRow, xyFromCell etc.

Answer (score 2):

Per Bill Huber's ([whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/664/whuber)) clever workaround:

> xmap = (FlowAccumulation(1) + 0.5)*cellsize + xmin
>
> ymap = (FlowAccumulation(64) + 0.5)*cellsize + ymin

Curtis Price has developed a [python script](https://geonet.esri.com/message/236639#236639) to do this:

```py
from arcpy.sa import *  
from arcpy import env as E  
# Calculate $$NROWS and $$NCOLS from current environment  
cellSize = float(E.cellSize)  
nrows = int((E.extent.YMax - E.extent.YMin) / float(E.cellSize))  
ncols = int((E.extent.XMax - E.extent.XMin)  / float(E.cellSize))  
# Bill Huber's method for $$XMAP and $$YMAP: "1" flows "right", "64" (63+1) flows "up"  
tmpg = CreateConstantRaster(1)  
xmap = (FlowAccumulation(tmpg) + 0.5) * cellSize + E.extent.XMin  
ymap = (FlowAccumulation(tmpg + 63) + 0.5) * cellSize + E.extent.YMin  
# applying the same method for $$ROWMAP and $$COLMAP  
colmap = Int(FlowAccumulation(tmpg))  
rowmap = Int(FlowAccumulation(tmpg + 3))  # flowdir "4" is "down" (top row is 0)
```

You can also still use $$XMAP/$$YMAP in ArcGIS 10+ by using the old arcgisscripting API

```py
import arcgisscripting  
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3) #This works in ArcGIS 10  
xmap='path/to/output'
ymap='path/to/output'

#you need to set appropriate extent and cellsize gp environments
result=gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra('$$XMAP', xmap)  
result=gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra('$$YMAP', ymap)
```

Comment: In the first example, what the (1) and (64) stand for?

Comment: @NewAtGis They are direction constants/codes. See the help - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Flow_Accumulation_works/009z00000062000000/

Comment: thanks @Luke. I got the FlowAcc rasters, but I do not know how to put to work that formula in the RasterCalculator. I mean, I have read the arcGIS documentation, and I got the idea of the direction codes. But, once I got the FlowAcc rasters, there is some other step to take before using the formula?

Comment: @NewAtGis You don't need to create flow accumulation rasters. Just open the raster calculator, set your environment (extent, snap raster and cell size) appropriately and enter the expression. ie `(FlowAccumulation(1) + 0.5)* cellsize + xmin` substituting cell size and xmin with the actual values.

Comment: Thanks @Luke. I have circumvented the problem, as I described here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149736/how-to-produce-a-raster-representing-x-coordinates?noredirect=1#comment219455_149736

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with R

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('dem.tif')
lon <- init(r, 'x', filename='lon.tif')
lat <- init(r, 'y', filename='lat.tif')
```

Comment: Your "another approach with R" was not tested. It doesn't work. See my "Editing Note 2".

Comment: That probably means that you are using an old version of R/raster.

Answer (score 0):

In 'Raster Calculator' tool ArcGIS (Desktop or Pro)

Where:

```
"Raster" --> Is your reference raster

LongitudeRaster =

((((FlowAccumulation(Con(IsNull("Raster"),1,1))+1)-1)/(float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","COLUMNCOUNT")[0])-1))*(float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","RIGHT")[0])-float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","LEFT")[0])))+float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","LEFT")[0])


LatitudeRaster =

((((FlowAccumulation(Con(IsNull("Raster"),64,64))+1)-1)/(float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","ROWCOUNT")[0])-1))*(float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","TOP")[0])-float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","BOTTOM")[0])))+float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("Raster","BOTTOM")[0])
```

Just to confirm, Compare minimum and maximum statistics and extent in the Raster results in information raster properties.

Cheers,

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_tool_that_can_generate_raster_longitude_and_latitude_in_Arcgis/2