# Identifying row and column location of a raster image using ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, map-algebra, syntaxerror

The [solution already available online](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010981) gives a python syntax error

> ERROR 000989
>
> Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line
>   1)

when I write

```
$$rowmap + 1
```

in map algebra expression.

Comment: That [Support Article](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010981) wrongly refers to ArcGIS 10. It only applies to ArcGIS <= 9.3x.

Answer (score 4):

The $$RowMap, $$ColMap, $$XMap and $$YMap variables (and some others) are no longer (directly) supported as of ArcGIS 10.0.

You can use it via [python](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/17736):

```
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(0, 0, 10, 10)  #Change to suit
# Or
arcpy.env.extent = "path to raster"
arcpy.env.cellSize = 1    #Change to suit
arcpy.gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra_sa("$$ROWMAP + 1"), "output_raster")
```

See also this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/149556/2856) and this [GeoNet post](https://geonet.esri.com/message/236639#236639).