# ArcGIS Raster Calculator reference xy coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, coordinates, raster-calculator

I'm using ArcGIS Raster Calculator (Spatial Analyst Tools > Map Algebra > Raster Calculator). I've got the correct extension licences and have run basic Con(,,) successfully.

I would like to reference XY coordinates in my calculations but don't know how. Any suggestions?

My use case is to check 2 partially overlapping rasters and create a new one, with interpolation in the overlap region based on X coordinate.

Pseudo code below showing what I want to achieve.

- [x] is where I want to reference the X coordinate of the cell being calculated
- the numbers 7000 and 7500 are X coordinates relating to my raster overlap, leading to an interpolation function being defined

  ```
  con ( IsNull("raster1") , "raster2" , con (IsNull("raster2"),"raster1", "raster1" + "raster2"*([x]-7000)/7500-7000 ))
  ```

I've got zero skill with Python, but am familiar with ModelBuilder and the old VB calculators etc. I'd prefer a solution that uses the GUI. If Python is the only way then I'll need a bit of hand holding to work out how to apply it and make it work.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204037/identifying-row-and-column-location-of-a-raster-image-using-arcgis-10-1