# Creating two rasters with the coordinates as cell values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have data that is related to its latitude and longitude (Northing/Easting). I am trying to create two rasters where the cell values are the UTM northings and UTM Eastings.

I am unsure how to populate those values to the cells in a raster.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: One doesn't "append" these values, one "populates" them, though you'll have the same value repeated across the raster in rows or columns, with an interval of the pixel size.

Comment: You have to use a couple of 'secret' tools http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204037/identifying-row-and-column-location-of-a-raster-image-using-arcgis-10-1