# Clip or extract a raster by row/column number in QGIS or ArcMap?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

I have a georeferenced raster. Instead of extracting or clipping it by a clip feature or co-ordinate, I need to clip it by row and column number.

i.e. I want BX.tif to be columns 2150:2400 and rows 1250:1650 of B2.tif.

Comment: Have you considered GDAL_Translate with -srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize? Supply the origin xoff, yoff in col/row then the xsize cols and ysize rows; note that xoff and yoff are offset from the upper left and the sizes shouldn't be negative. ArcGIS has Clip_management http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009n000000 but that requires an envelope in georeferenced coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addressed this using Michael Miles-Stimson's comment - in gdal

gdal_translate -srcwin 1250 2150 401 251 input.tif output.tif

Answer (score 1):

Set environment extent and cell size to your raster. Go to python window and type:

```
>>> arcpy.gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra_sa("$$ROWMAP + 1")
>>> arcpy.gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra_sa("$$COLMAP + 1")
```

rename outputs in table of content and use field calculator:

```
Con(("COLS" <= 50)  & ("COLS" >= 10) & ("ROWS" <= 50) & ("ROWS" >= 20),1)
```

Convert output to polygon and set environment extent to it.
Use raster calculator to compute extract, e.g. type "DEM"

Credits go to [@Luke](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204037/identifying-row-and-column-location-of-a-raster-image-using-arcgis-10-1)