# Setting ArcMap to get control points in pixels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I need to export control points from ArcMap to use it with Matlab. I want to get these points in pixel not in the meter as you can see the below image
[image]

these images are 1400X900 px. I expect point 1 = (0,0) and 3 (900,1400).

what should I do to make the control points in pixel?

Comment: See @Luke solution on creating column and row rasters. Sample you points afterwards https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204037/identifying-row-and-column-location-of-a-raster-image-using-arcgis-10-1

Comment: It should be the X Source and Y Source as for column and row; the first row is at the top and increases downward. From the screenshot none of those values are metres.

Comment: I don't know how to use python with ArcMap. Is there any more simple solution since I use ArcMap to extract cp only - with subpixel accuracy.