# Extracting value from three different raster for same pixel/position as CSV or tabulated dataset using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have computed Hydrologic Sensitivity Index (HSI) as a raster for a region using slope, Hydraulic conductivity, Depth to the Restrictive Layer and Flow accumulation. All the files are in rasters of same pixel size. The rasters are float type rasters.

Now, I would like to plot Hydraulic conductivity vs HSI, Depth vs HSI for every pixel etc.. In other words, for each pixel, I need the computed HSI value, Depth, Hydraulic conductivity, and Flow accumulation in a column or dataframe.

How can I accomplish this in ArcMap?

What I tried:

1. First I tried to use the Combine tool. But Combine tool doesn't seem to work with float raster even if I convert it into integers there will be too many unique values to make this combination.

What if two different pixels had same values?

In that case, I do not think this tool will show those two pixel separately (right?).

2. Convert each Raster to Int Raster than to Polygon than use Union tool. I couldn't accomplish this because the HSI raster file is very detailed and takes too long to convert to polygon and seems to crash in the middle.

What I think could work:

1. I know there is a way to convert Raster data into a Numpytable. This way I will have four separate Numpy table for each of the four data but how will I map the value in such a way that i ensure that they are for the same pixel?

I know I can use `arcpy.Describe.polygon.OIDFieldName` to create id in Polygon but is there similar tool for Raster. But i am also not sure when I am using this tool for four different raster.

Will the pixel in the same location get the same oid values?

Comment: If they all have the same dimensions to begin with then try `arcpy.NumpyArrayToRaster()` 4 times, `np.dstack()` to create a `(y_size, x_size, 4)`-shaped array, then `stack.reshape((-1, 4))` to achieve your 4 columns

Comment: @mikewatt Thank you for this suggestion. They all have the same pixel size. when i do the stacking using ```np.dstack()``` how does the function know that it is maping the values for the same pixel without us providing any id to compare to (like we do while doing a polygon join)?

Comment: They all have to have the same width, height, pixel size, and geographic location for this to work.  But if they do, then the arrays that you load will all have the same shape and the order of pixels will be consistent across all of them.  Any numpy operations like `dstack()` will always preserve the order as appropriate ([see the examples](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html))

Comment: If you really after entire raster (not just streams) compute and combine rows and columns using https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204037/identifying-row-and-column-location-of-a-raster-image-using-arcgis-10-1 You can use Sample to collect as many rasters values as you want.

Comment: @mikewatt When i try your suggestion i run into two problems:   1. when i use ```arcpy.RasterToNumpyArray()``` i get extremely large negative values in my array. I checked my Raster file and it seems to be fine. Also, all three raster shows exactly the same value and all large negative number.      2.i ignored the large values and went to the next step. I was able to stack the values from three raster together but i couldnt convert the array into gistable. Is there a easy way to export the final array out of arcpy environment? Any suggestions?

Comment: @FelixIP I tried to follow your suggestion but i didnt know what to look for in the post you shared. Could you please let me know what is the function i are should be using?

Comment: The very large negative number is probably the nodata value.  You could replace it with `np.nan` if your arrays are floating point type, `array[np.min(array) = np.nan]`, or alternatively read the numpy docs about masked arrays.  I don't know what gistable is or what your eventual goal is, but if you just need to persist the results then `np.save()` can write the array to disk so you can `np.load()` it from another Python environment.

Comment: @mikewatt Your methods worked as well! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set environment extent and cell size to your raster. Make sure workspace is also specified.
In Python window type:

```
arcpy.gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra_sa("$$ROWMAP","nRow")
```

This will produce integer raster of rows:

Similarly compute raster of columns:

```
arcpy.gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra_sa("$$COLMAP","nCol")
```

[image]

In Arcmap Options increase number of unique numbers to render to nr*nc, where nr is number of columns in you raster, nc -columns.
Use Combine tool from spatial analyst to combine nRow and nCol into single raster where each cell is unique:

[image]

Use Sample to sample your rasters, e.g.

```
arcpy.gp.Sample_sa("FACC;FDIR", "Combine", "in_memory/abc", "NEAREST", "Value")
```

Output table will have all you need, even coordinates of cell centres:

[image]

Comment: This worked so well. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps mark it as solved, please.

Comment: i tried to upvote it last time but it said i dont have enought "reputation" to upvote a post.. I didnt know there was a "Solved" button. I checked a mark in your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, cheers  mate

Comment: sorry to bug you again. Previously i wrote a code for a small subarea and the process worked fine. But when i do the same thng on whole area, I am getting following error after creating nrows and ncols, and increasing render limit (78403059) while using Combine tools:  Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) ExecuteError: ERROR 001143: Background server threw an exception.

Comment: Yes, process will not work for real life rasters,  too many unique numbers. Possible solution is split original into multiple rectangles and merge outputs. At every iteration first thing is set env.extent to rectangle and use snap raster.

Comment: It's too big for numpy as well.

Comment: Btw correlation IS comparable using rasters.

Comment: I also thought the issue was the large number of rows to process. Is there a efficient way to move through a raster (HSI in my case) piece by piece, while creating a rectangle. And using that rectangle as an extent to clip the other input rasters and doing all the necessary process. Also, i donot understand the need of snap raster? One more question, is it possible to set the "number of unique rasters to render" inside a loop?

Comment: Investigate split raster tool, perhaps create fishnet before. This will create a list of small rasters, so shuffle through them saving output table with unique names. If rasters are small enough, forget about rendering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123479/discussion-between-felixip-and-samrat).

Answer (score 1):

A variant on [@FelixIP's approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/394523/115) is first take one of your rasters and run it through the raster to point tool. This creates a point for every pixel. You now have a point dataset which you could apply a selection to, e.g. a particular catchment, then run it through the Sample tool as he describes above.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation helped.

Comment: It is an option, but much slower, than one with rasters only, I guess it is so, because no shapes is created in the process.